# PHP Curl CookieJar file format

Tags: php, curl

As you guys know, you can send cookies with a Curl request. So here is a example:

```html
<?php
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/foo.bin");
 
  /* get cookies from an existing file */
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookies.txt");
 
  ret = curl_easy_perform(curl);
 
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
?>
```

But what is the format of `/tmp/cookies.txt`?

Thanks!

Comment: https://ec.haxx.se/http-cookies.html

Comment: @CBroe it doesnt shows a template/format

Comment: Quote, _“The file format curl uses for cookies is called the Netscape cookie format because it was once the file format used by browsers and then you could easily tell curl to use the browser's cookies! [...] As a convenience, curl also supports a cookie file being a set of HTTP headers that set cookies.”_ And if that still isn’t enough for you to go from there, then you could also check what such a file contains after cURL has received a cookie from an example request.

Answer (score 0):

The Netscape cookie file format is text-based and stores one cookie per line. Lines that start with # are treated as comments. Each line that specifies a single cookie consists of seven text fields separated with TAB characters. A valid line must end with a newline character.

```
#domain         Include Subdomains      Path        Secure      Expires at      Name        Value
.example.com    TRUE                    /           TRUE        1628330848      id          1234
```

Secure: send/receive over HTTPS only.

Expires at: seconds since Jan 1st, 1970, or 0 for session cookies.

More info: https://curl.se/docs/http-cookies.html